# $U\cap W$ isomorphic to $\ker(T)$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U,W$ be the subspaces of a vector space $V$. The map of $U\times W: \to V$ is given by: $(u,w)\to u-w$. Show that the kernel is isomorphic to $U\cap W$.

$T:U\times W\to V$

$T(u,w)=0\:\:\text{iff}\:\:u=w,u\in U,w \in W$

$u=w\:\:\text{iff}\:\:u,w\in U\cap W$

So $\ker(T)={u,w\in U\times W:f(u,w)=0}=U\cap W$

So $\ker(T)=U\cap W$

Therefore, $\dim(ker(T))=\dim(U\cap W)$ which means $T$ is surjective and since $\ker(T)=U\cap W$ it is obviously injective, therefore it is an isomorphism.

**Questions:**

**1)** Have I proved $\ker(T)$ is isomorphic to $U\cap W$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you assume $ker(T)=0$?

Comment: What is $v$ in $(u, w)\rightarrow u-v$?

Comment: @PJK Please check my edit, there was mistake  it is $u-w$. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @Mickey Please check my edit, if that solves your problem.

Comment: @Mickey Probably you are right the $\ker(T)={u,w\in U\times W:f(u,w)=0}=U\cap W$, right?

Comment: @PJK Please check out my last update!

Comment: @Mickey Thanks for your insight, please check out my last edit!

Answer (score 2):

There is a correct idea there but it's badly written. Here is a clear proof:

$ (u,w) \in \ker(T)$ iff $u=w$.

Therefore, $\ker(T) = \{ (v,v) : v \in U \cap W \}$.

Then the map $\ker(T) \to U \cap W$ given by $v \mapsto (v,v)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Why are you making use of the $(v,v)$ when $v\notin U\cap W$?

Comment: @PedroGomes, I'm not. If $v \in \ker T$ then $v \in U \cap W$. If using the letter $v$ is confusing you, try something else, like $x$.

Comment: I mean $v\in V$

Comment: Is $\ker(T) = U \cap W$?

Answer (score 2):

If $(u, v) \in ker(T)$, then $u=v$. Clearly the opposite implication is also true, and so $ker(T) = \{(u, u): u \in K\} $, where $ K \subset V $ is to be found.
From the last expression is clear that $u\in K$ implies $u \in  U \cap W $. On the other hand, if $ u \in U \cap W $ then $ (u, u) \in U \times W $ and $ (u, u) \in ker(T)$, hence $ u \in K$. So $K = U \cap W $, and the isomorphism is apparent.

Comment: Is $ \ker(T) = U \cap W$?

Comment: @PedroGomes not exactly, because they are subspaces of different vector spaces. But they are isomorphic via $K \ni u \mapsto (u, u) \in ker(T)$. Everything in this relation is well defined for what is said in the answer.

Comment: They are not subspaces of different vector spaces. $T(u,w)=0$ if u=v. u=w only in $U\cap W$. Do not forget the kernel takes value  on $U\times W$ and $U\cap W\subset U\times W$

Answer (score 0):

Define a map $\phi:\ker T\rightarrow U\cap W$ as below:

Let $(u, w)\in \ker T$. Then $T(u, w)=0$ so $u-w=0\Rightarrow u=w$. Let us call this element $v$ i.e., $u=w=v$. Then $v\in U\cap W$ and every element of $\ker T$ is of the form $(u, w)=(v, v)$. Define $$\phi(u, w)=\phi(v, v)=v$$ which is the map defined by lhf.

Now to show $\phi$ an isomorphism, show that it is a surjective linear transformation with $\ker\phi =0$.